# SQLite on Mono Shared Cache Mode?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

Does Mono.Data.SQLite support in-memory databases using Shared Cache Mode? I'm getting an ArgumentException complaining about the format of the data source URI string. The connection string I'm attempting to use is:

```
URI=file::memory:?cache=shared;Version=3
```

I've also tried with the `Data Source` connection string property, with similar results.

(For reference, this is in the context of an iPhone MonoTouch application.)